# Unable to create a stable websocket implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, keystone

Usecase:
This runs on the server side (Keystone) of an Android application

- App connects to the socket with the user's accesstoken
- App shows indicators for all the other user's who are connected to the socket
- When a user changes some data in the app, a **force refresh** is send over the socket to all the "online" users so that they know to fetch the latest data

Main problem:

- It works until a client loses it's internet connection right in between the intervals. Then the socket connection is closed and not reopened.

I don't know if it's a problem with my implementation or a problem with implementation on the client side

Implementation uses:

- https://github.com/websockets/ws
- More specifically https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections

Here is the implementation on the server:

```
const clients = {};
let wss = null;

const delimiter = '_';

/**
 * Clients are stored as "companyId_deviceId"
 */
function getClients() {
  return clients;
}

function sendMessage(companyId, msg) {
  try {
    const clientKey = Object.keys(clients).find((a) =>     a.split(delimiter)[0] === companyId.toString());

    const socketForUser = clients[clientKey];
    if (socketForUser && socketForUser.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      socketForUser.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    } else {
      console.info(`WEBSOCKET: could not send message to company ${companyId}`);
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(`WEBSOCKET: could not send message to company     ${companyId}: `, ex);
  }
}

function noop() { }

function heartbeat() {
  this.isAlive = true;
}

function deleteClient(clientInfo) {
  delete clients[`${clientInfo.companyId}${delimiter}${clientInfo.deviceId}`];

  // notify all clients
  forceRefreshAllClients();
}

function createSocket(server) {
  wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

  wss.on('connection', async (ws, req) => {
    try {
      // verify socket connection
      let { query: { accessToken } } = url.parse(req.url, true);
      const decoded = await tokenHelper.decode(accessToken);

      // add new websocket to clients store
      ws.isAlive = true;
      clients[`${decoded.companyId}${delimiter}${decoded.deviceId}`] = ws;
      console.info(`WEBSOCKET: ➕ Added client for company ${decoded.companyId} and device ${decoded.deviceId}`);

      await tokenHelper.verify(accessToken);

      // notify all clients about new client coming up
      // including the newly created socket client...
      forceRefreshAllClients();

      ws.on('pong', heartbeat);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error('WEBSOCKET: WebSocket Error', ex);
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'ERROR', data: { status: 401, title: 'invalid token' } }));
    }

    ws.on('close', async () => {
      const location = url.parse(req.url, true);
      const decoded = await tokenHelper.decode(location.query.accessToken);

      deleteClient({ companyId: decoded.companyId, deviceId: decoded.deviceId });
   });
});

  // Ping pong on interval will remove the client if the client has no internet connection
  setInterval(() => {
    Object.keys(clients).forEach((clientKey) => {
      const ws = clients[clientKey];
      if (ws.isAlive === false) return ws.terminate();

      ws.isAlive = false;
      ws.ping(noop);
    });
  }, 15000);
}

function forceRefreshAllClients() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    Object.keys(clients).forEach((key) => {
      const companyId = key.split(delimiter)[0];
      sendMessage(companyId, createForcedRefreshMessage());
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: clients should also have a `setInterval` to check for server connection and reconnect if down.